# Remove IP with ip command in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, shell-script

If I add two IPs like this:

1. ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth2
2. ip addr add 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth2

and then I try to delete one of like this:

1. ip addr del 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth2

BOTH IPs will be deleted and I don't know how to handle it.

Any one knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `ip addr list dev eth2` after your two `add` commands, you will see something like this (emphasis mine):

```
2: eth2:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
     link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
     inet 1.1.1.1/24 scope global eth2
     inet 1.1.1.2/24 scope global secondary eth2
```

The important part to notice is that Linux treats the second address as secondary to the first one, as they are in the same logical subnet (/24). Deleting the secondary address has no impact on the primary one, but vice versa.

If you need to add/del addresses in 1.1.1.0/24, you probably should first add one address which is always valid (e.g. 1.1.1.99/24) and then add 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 as secondary addresses. Then you can add/delete the .1 and .2 address at will.

If this is not possible, then you can also temporarily add 1.1.1.2**/32** before deleting 1.1.1.1. [This will maintain connectivity for all connections from outside your network](http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:freeing-the-primary-ip-address/). Depending on your network setup (i.e., whether your router supports proxy ARP), you may also be able to use 1.1.1.2**/0** temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Something else is likely doing things behind your back. NetworkManager is a known offender.

Run `ip monitor` while executing your commands, and see if someone else is modifying the configuration.